# How to see the Hodge filtrations vary holomorphically directly

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I have asked this question on Stack Exchange, ["Why the Hodge filtrations vary holomorphically"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2779430/why-the-hodge-filtrations-vary-holomorphically), but I have not got any reply, therefore I have revised this question a little bit, and post it here on MO.

Suppose we have a fibration over the unit disc $\Delta$ of $\mathbb{C}$,
\begin{equation}
\pi: X \rightarrow \Delta
\end{equation}
such that all the fibers are smooth Kahler manifolds. The for every $\varphi \in \Delta$, we have a Hodge decomposition
\begin{equation}
H^n(X_{\varphi}, \mathbb{C})=\oplus_{p+q=n}H^{p,q}(X_{\varphi})
\end{equation}
which further determines a Hodge filtration,
\begin{equation}
F^p_{\varphi}:=\oplus_{k \geq p}H^{k,n-k}(X_{\varphi})
\end{equation}
**Question 1**: From references, $H^{p,q}(X_{\varphi})$ varies smoothly with respect to $\varphi$, i.e. $\cup_{\varphi}H^{p,q}(X_{\varphi})$ forms a smooth bundle over $\Delta$. How to prove this?

**Question 2**: From references (again), $F^p_{\varphi}$ varies holomorphically with respect to $\varphi$, i.e. $\cup_{\varphi} F^p_{\varphi}$ forms a holomorphic bundle over $\Delta$. How to prove this?

Edit, I realise I have not stated this question clearly. I mean are there direct ways to prove that $H^{p,q}(X_{\varphi})$ (resp. $F_{\varphi}^p$) varies smoothly (resp. holomorphically)? I.e. $H^{p,q}(X_{\varphi})$ are spanned by harmonic forms $\Psi_{\varphi}$, how to see these harmonic forms varies smoothly? Similarly how to see $F_{\varphi}^p$ varies holomorphically directly from the harmonic forms which span it?

Comment: The Hodge filtration is the filtration on cohomology induced by the stupid filtration of the de Rham complex. More precisely, if $\Omega^{\leq p}_X$ is the complex with degree $i$ term $\Omega^i_X$ if $i\leq p$, zero if $i>p$, then $F^p H^n(X, \Omega^\bullet_X)$ is the image of the map $H^n(X, \Omega^{\leq p}_X)\to H^n(X, \Omega^\bullet_X)$. This makes clear sense in families.

Comment: Rather than asking this type of questions here, wouldn't it better to choose a good book (e.g. Voisin's *Hodge theory and complex algebraic geometry*) and learn the subject?

Comment: @PiotrAchinger That's a good answer although it seems a bit rude to the poor filtration...

Comment: @Piotr Achinger Thank you for your answer. I am sorry that I haven’t stated this question clearly. Suppose we have a harmonic form represents an element $H^{p,q}$ over the point $\varphi$, how to see it varies smoothly, while a linear subspace varies holomorphically directly? Like is there a direct way to see solutions of laplacian will vary smoothly if we vary the laplacian.

Comment: Piotr shows that $F^p$ varies holomorphically; hence $\overline{F^p}$ varies antiholomorphically.  Now intersect them...